# Does not pick up my wireless network

Tags: wifi

I cannot or the operating system cannot find my wireless network. Clicking on the network icon only shows the wired connection. How do I get my wireless network connected? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It may be a driver issue, please update the question with the brand/model of your computer.

Comment: Please run `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" && sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Moth" && lshw | grep product | head -n1 && lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 && rfkill list` then click [edit] to add the facts to your question. Please do not click Add Comment, please use [edit] instead. Editing tips are at https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code .